# Have account but no cell phone. Will GitHub's new authentication require me to buy a cell phone?

Tags: github, authentication

I am a retired person who mainly sits at home. I don't need a cell phone. Will the change in authentication methods coming to GitHub force me to buy a cell phone? Are there alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

GitHub has been using [2FA with email](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/securing-your-account-with-two-factor-authentication-2fa) for a while. I couldn't find anywhere where they said they will be forcing users to signup with mobile phones. Email should do fine for the foreseeable future.